# Jupyter notebook not opening up from command due to attribute error

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter-lab, timing

When I type 'Jupyter Lab' in my Pycharm command I get the following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\ozzya\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 64, in <module>
        clocku = clocks = clock = time.clock
    AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

I looked online and tried multiple different solutions from:

- Downgrading from Python 3.8 to 3.7
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Jupyter
- Changing `time.clock` to `time.time` and other various suggested methods in `timing.py` file

I feel that I have exhausted a lot of my options at the moment to fix this issue and would appreciate any further recommendations.

Comment: why you want to open it  in pycharm? You can open it separately on your browser also

Comment: @Chandan Malla - It's the same - whichever way I access (via conda, browser, Jupyter command etc.)

Comment: I run it using this commmand /home/chandanmalla/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook , you should also try using absolute path You can also try this python3 -m jupyer notebook